# Please Help me identify my Bike Logo

Tags: frames, identify-this-bike

Hello can someone help me identify my bike Frame?. It has this weird Logo and a Serial number of : "2948" . It has Suntour Dropouts likely NJS.

Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: A photo of the whole frame would probably help. Velobase's [head badge database](http://velobase.com/ListHeadBadges.aspx) might be a useful place to look.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Hello sir i've uploaded a picture of my Frame here : https://imgur.com/pM4LeDI. Thank you!

Comment: I don't think that it is even a logo or a head badge. I think it might just be an ornamental cutout in the frame lug.

Comment: Thank you very much! @Carbonsideup . Nothing Special with the frame

Comment: I agree with Carbon side up ... just looks ornamental to me.